# Electrical issue with 2009 Chevy Malibu

Tags: electrical, chevrolet, malibu

Was wondering if anybody is experiencing the same issues as I am with my 2009 Chevy Malibu. In the evening when it gets dark the door locks will start going haywire when the car is not running and headlights will go on and off by myself. Anyone know how to fix this issue? Or any suggestions? Would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!